# Is there any way that uboot will know about the kernel boot status

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux, u-boot

Once the Uboot loads the Linux kernel image (ZImage) onto the ram, it invokes it (could be using bootz, bootm or some other commands based on the type of the kernel Image) and then the control goes to booting the kernel. Does the uboot will be informed about the kernel boot result?, means, whether the kernel booting went through completely or got stuck in the middle because of errors?.

I looked at do_bootz, do_bootm_states and boot_selected_os api's in the uboot src code to see if there is any way to know about the final kernel boot result, but I couldn't able to figured it out.

Details:
U-boot Version: 2017.03-rc2
api's are available at: cmd/bootz.c and bootm.c files.

If any one in this community knows about it or have an idea about it, please explain to me or point me to the correct path.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Vamsi Chagari

Comment: *"Does the uboot will be informed about the kernel boot result?"* -- No.  U-Boot does not *"invoke"* the kernel, but transfers (full) control of the system to the kernel.  There is no guarantee that the kernel does not clobber the C runtime environment or the text of U-Boot, so there is no assumption that U-Boot can be executed again.  Only well-behaved "standalone" programs that conform to U-Boot conventions can "return" control back to U-Boot after a `go` command.

Answer (score 2):

After bootm, booti, bootz transfer control to the kernel the memory formerly used by U-Boot will be reused by the operating system. As U-Boot is no longer in memory it cannot be informed about the operating system status.

If you use the bootefi command the U-Boot implementation of the UEFI runtime services stays in memory while the operating system is starting. The UEFI services can be called by the operating system. These include services relating to variables. One use of UEFI variables is the definition of the boot sequence.

Unfortunately UEFI variables are not yet completetly implemented in U-Boot (as of version v2018.07). They currently cannot be accessed after exiting boot services.

Comment: Hi Xypron, thank you for the explanation, I appreciate your time and efforts. I always thought these kind of reliability booting procedure or feature is all-ready available in the U-boot.

Comment: I will explore the UEFI compatible commands in the U-boot and see if I can add the features I would need.